# How can i read my Buffer, AT command in TeraTerm for Mbed Aduino Nucleo and JSN270

Tags: c, at-command, mbed, teraterm, nucleo

I have a Question of my Nucleo.

I am study about JSN270 for aduino and Nucleo, my system environment is

```
Bottom : Nucleo (L053R8)
Middle : JSN 270 Aduino shield v1.1
Top : JSN 270
```

And i used Teraterm (terminal).

I can bright to LED and printing (ex : pc.printf ) but, i have manu problems about AT command in Teraterm.

So, this is my source code, and result is next image:

[image: result]

```
#include "mbed.h"
Serial pc(SERIAL_TX, SERIAL_RX);
UARTSerial serial = UARTSerial(D1, D0, 9600);
ATCmdParser at = ATCmdParser(&serial, "\r\n");
int value;
char buffer[100];

int main()
{        
at.send("at+ver") && at.recv("OK");
at.read(buffer, 10);
pc.printf("ASD : %s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: What is the JSN270 supposed to return? If you run [SerialPassthrough](https://os.mbed.com/users/mbedAustin/code/SerialPassthrough/) on the board, do you get proper output from the JSN270?

Comment: Just working on Nucleo, doesn't work JSN270